# SwiftUI and Measurement conversions : only first conversion is performed

Tags: swiftui, foundation, measurement

I've been struggling with Measurements when used in SwiftUI. I want to be able to convert measurements on the fly, but only the first conversion is working. All subsequent ones fail.

I've managed to narrow it down to a reproducible test case.

First, a quick check to see that Foundation works:

```swift
// Let’s check that conversion is possible, and works.

var test = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 13.37, unit: .meters)
print("Original value: \(test.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
// prints: Original value: 13.37 m

test.convert(to: .centimeters)
print("In centimeters: \(test.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
// prints: In centimeters: 1,337 cm

test.convert(to: .kilometers)
print("In kilometers: \(test.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
// prints: In kilometers: 0.01337 km

test.convert(to: .meters)
print("Back to meters: \(test.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
// prints: Back to meters: 13.37 m
```

Okay, so it works on the Foundation level. I can convert measurements back and forth, many times.

Now run this ContentView below, and click/tap any button. First one will succeed, the other ones will fail.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var distance = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 13.37, unit: .meters)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Distance = \(distance.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")

            Button("Convert to cm") { print("Convert to cm"); distance.convert(to: .centimeters) }

            Button("Convert to m")  { print("Convert to m");  distance.convert(to: .meters) }

            Button("Convert to km") { print("Convert to km"); distance.convert(to: .kilometers) }

        }

        .onChange(of: distance, perform: { _ in
            print("→ new distance =  \(distance.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
        })

        .frame(minWidth: 300)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is reproducible both on macOS and iOS.

Why on Earth does the first conversion succeed, then all subsequent ones fail? The onChange isn't even triggered.

I'm on Xcode 13.3, macOS 12.3, iOS 15.4

Comment: Replacing `distance.convert()` with `distance = distance.converted()` does the same.

Comment: OK, I've found why SwiftUI doesn't pick up the changes: the hash of `distance` doesn't change anymore past the first conversion. Now, as to why... and how to circumvent this…

Comment: Progress: there's one hash for integer values (cm, mm), and floating-point values (m, km) have another hash.
Example:
```
Original value: 13,37 m -- hash is -2107666214957961083
In centimeters: 1 337 cm -- hash is 2257762227114217319
In millimeters: 13 370 mm -- hash is 2257762227114217319
In kilometers: 0,01337 km -- hash is -2107666214957961083
Back to meters: 13,37 m -- hash is -2107666214957961083
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `Measurement`'s header you'll see it is a `ReferenceConvertible` and the docs for that state "A decoration applied to types that are backed by a Foundation reference type." so it probably doesn't have the value semantics that `@State` requires for SwiftUI to detect changes. Here is a workaround:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MTContentViewConfig: Equatable {
    var distance = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 13.37, unit: .meters)
    var seed = 0

    public mutating func convert(to otherUnit: UnitLength) {
        distance.convert(to: otherUnit)
        seed += 1
    }
}

struct MTContentView: View {
    @State var config = MTContentViewConfig()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Distance = \(config.distance.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
            
            Button("Convert to cm") { print("Convert to cm")
                config.convert(to: .centimeters) }

            Button("Convert to m")  { print("Convert to m")
                config.convert(to: .meters) }

            Button("Convert to km") { print("Convert to km")
                config.convert(to: .kilometers) }

        }

        .onChange(of: config) { newVal in
            print("→ new distance =  \(newVal.distance.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number)))")
        }

        .frame(minWidth: 300)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

By the way instead of doing manual formatting I would recommend supplying `Text` with a `MeasurementFormatter`, this way `Text` will update the `UILabel` automatically when region settings change.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, reading the docs for ReferenceConvertible. It seems to be a kind of hybrid between a struct and a class, hence the bizarre hashes. (And manual formatting is just for the example.)

Comment: I added a workaround you could try

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

`Measurement` has not gotten a lot of love in the last few years from Apple. While this should work in SwiftUI, it is not. The answer is to do the conversion in a view model class, and let it update the published value. Something like this:

```
class MeasurementConverterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var distance: Measurement<UnitLength>
    
    init(distance: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        self.distance = distance
    }
    
    public func convertToCM() {
        distance.convert(to: .centimeters)
    }
    
    public func convertToM() {
        distance.convert(to: .meters)
    }
    
    public func convertToKM() {
        distance.convert(to: .kilometers)
    }
}
```

This does work, though I would check [Open Radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/page/1) to see if anyone posted a bug report AND file the bug. This should work just as you coded in SwiftUI.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking of just creating a boxing struct with its own hash method, that would be easier to (de)serialize, but your approach is valuable.